# Finding half life of a given decay path given percentage decayed in each path

Tags: radioactivity

> $^{64}_{29}\ce{Cu}$(" half life" =$12.8$ "hours" ) decay by $\beta^{-}$- emission (38%), $\beta^+$- emission(19%), and electron capture (43%). Write the decay products and calculate partial half lives for each of the decay processes. Source: JEE Advanced
>
> Soltn:
> Half life of beta-= $\frac{}{}=\frac{12.8}{.38}$, beta+ =$ \frac{12.8}{.19}$ and electron capture$ \frac{12.8}{.43}$

From googling I find, that the term partial half life is popularly known as branching fraction:

> the branching fraction (or branching ratio) for a decay is the fraction of particles which decay by an individual decay mode with respect to the total number of particles which decay
>
> [Source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Branching_fraction)

**Question:** I don't get why the half life of each individual path is the total half life divided by the fraction of nuclei decayed that way. I foudnd this [related post](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/34634/how-to-find-the-average-half-life-of-radioactive-nuclide-which-undergoes-two-dif) but there it involves a the actual reaction being given.

I also found this [wiki article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_decay#:%7E:text=Terms%20%22partial%20half%2Dlife%22,a%20certain%20quantity%20is%20halved.) on half life, but I am not sure how to use it to derive this.

Comment: Deriving the relation of the half life, partial half lifes and probability percentage of the particular decay path is not complicated algebraic exercise.

Comment: What equations should one begin with? @Poutnik I'll try for a self answer then

Comment: Equations for the reaction kinetic of the first order - all radioactive decays follow it.

Comment: The solution given does seem strange but maybe something common in study of radioactive decay. The Cu decays with a single half life and each product appears with the same half life, 12.8 hours even though the rate constants for each product can be different.  If the rate constants are (in order as above)  $k_1, k_2, k_3$ then $\beta^-$ appears with fraction (branching ratio)  $k_1/(k_1+k_2+k_3)=0.38$ and so on and the sum is the _rate constant_ for decay of the Cu which is easily related to the half life. I suspect  partial half lives means get k's for each product and convert to half lives.

Comment: Note that "partial half lifes" is not very useful concept, it is better to stay with the overall half life, decay constants and decay mode probability.

Comment: How is the percent of product equal to fraction of rate constant over total ?? @poryphrin Secondly if the equation is true, how would I find rate constants anyways

Comment: It is easier to use rate constants than half lives. You have three equations and three unknowns, $k_1,k_2,k_3$ you know the sum of these given by $\ln(2)/t_{1/2}$ and each ratio, 0.38 etc.